# Одиночный тап, созданный через UITapGestureRecognizer, не срабатывает на UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, gestures, uibutton

У меня есть кнопка, UI Button. У этой кнопки нет никакого экшена, я хочу этот экшен вызывать в обработке тапа. Я создал событие одиночного тапа через UITapGestureRecognizer. Когда я тапаю мимо кнопки, событие срабатывает. Когда тапаю по кнопке, я вижу анимация прожатия, но событие на срабатывает. Также я создал двойной тап, с ним всё отлично.

**Вопрос №1**
Что делать с одиночным тапом? Как заставить его проходить по кнопке?

**Вопрос №2**
Как мне в обработчике тапа получить кнопку, над которой был совершен тап? Если быть точнее, то мне нужно узнать текст на кнопке.

Вот выдержки из кода:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...

    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "singleTap:")
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)

    let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "doubleTap:")
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
    singleTap.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(doubleTap)

    ...
}

func doubleTap(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .Ended {
        print("doubleTap")
    }
}

func singleTap(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .Ended {
        print("singleTap")
    }
}

func addButton(time:String, x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat, width:CGFloat, height:CGFloat, tag: Int) -> UIButton {
    let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
    button.setTitle(time, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.tag = tag
    self.scrollView.addSubview(button)
    return button
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне помогли на основном сайте: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736552/single-tap-created-by-uitapgesturerecognizer-doesnt-work-on-uibutton/34736789#34736789

Нужно было вешать тапы не на вьху, а на кнопки.

```
let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "singleTap:")
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
button.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Ответ на #2

Вы можете это сделать несколькими способами:

- Объект UIGestureRecognizer имеет свойство [view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/view) (The view the
  gesture recognizer is attached to.), с помощью которого вы можете
  получить свою кнопку, ну и дале изменить ее текст c помощью
  [setTitle:forState:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle:forState:).
- При создании кнопки указывать [tag](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tag), в хендлере получат этот tag, дальше по логике.